# htaccess RewriteRule fails if page not found

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache

I'm trying to user `RewriteRule` in my `.htaccess` file to redirect example.com/page to example.com/page.php (or add the `.php` to any requested file that does not have an extension.

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(.*)\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [R]    #I also tried ^(.+)$ with no effect
```

from ["Spoofing" a 404 not found error with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630996/spoofing-a-404-not-found-error-with-htaccess)

I tried this with no other `RewriteRule`s in my .htaccess, but it still just resolves to the 404 error page via the `ErrorDocument`. All other rules I try to use also get completely skipped if the requested page is not found. Any rule I specify works if the requested url resolves to an existing page or directory.

I have a Godaddy shared hosting Linux server. I am pretty sure that I cannot edit my httpd.conf file.

I'm wondering if anybody could tell me why my `RewriteRule`s are ignored when the original request is not a file or directory - when it doesn't exist.

Thank you for any help.

**EDIT**:
I now see that if I go to mysite.com/index.php RewriteRule works. If I go to mysite.com/index RewriteRule does not work. If I go to a page that does not exist at all - mysite.com/asdfasdfsadf then my RewriteRule works. So it only fails on the extensionless version of an existing url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(.*)\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [R]
```

Comment: Same result. If I go to mysite.com/index.php it loads, but if I go to mysite.com/index then it tells me "The requested URL /index was not found on this server."

Comment: Not 100% sure what all I did. I've been messing with my .htaccess for a few hours. But I ended up adding `Options -MultiViews` above `RewriteEngine On`. I also added `RewriteBase /`. This resolves my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I think,

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

should help.

```
RewriteBase /
```

is only for **Directory** or **Location**, not for whole **VirtualHost**!

Comment: Thanks. I've actually ended up going a different route. I have my .htaccess visually remove the extension then add a trailing slash for all HTML and PHP files. I then them internally redirect to `page_load.php`, and I `include()` a template and the requested URL.

Answer (score 1):

I did come up with a rudimentary solution using my 404 error page. In my htaccess, I add:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
```

And then in 404.php, I have the following code:

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$ext_pos = strpos($request, ".");
if (!$ext_pos){
    $request = $request.".php";
    header("Location: ".$protocol.$domain.$request);
}
```

It is functional, but does not do exactly as I desire, unfortunately. I want all of the re-writing to work within the .htaccess file.