# How to use mod_rewrite to direct anything but PHP pages to index.php?

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a question that is a bit confusing. I'm trying to understand mod_rewrite but I am pretty confused by it.

What I'm trying to do is redirect all URLs such as /settings/account or /user/user123 to index.php. A PHP script (which I already created) uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to break the URL down into  pieces then uses include. For example it would include settings.php?page=account or user.php?uid=user123.

But if the URL is /settings.php?page=account or /user.php?uid=user123 I don't want it to be redirected through index. In other words, if the URl has a file extension, just go to that file, but if it doesn't (like /settings) go to index.php to process where it should go.

How can this be done? Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the commonplace [redirect-every-url-which-has-no-corresponding-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388652/htaccess-rewriterule-fails-if-page-not-found) approach, you can also try your approach. To redirect anything without dot to a common script, use:

```
 RewriteRule  ^([^.]*)$  index.php?path=$1
```

You might want to exclude some URLs still, like `images/` or `css/` etc. Use a simple RewriteCond before the rule then:

```
 RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !images/
 RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !css/
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) directive with `!-f` and `!-d` patterns.

`RewriteCond` checks whether a user's HTTP request matches provided condition. In your case, you would want to check if a requested file (which is provided in a variable `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`) already exists on your document root using the `!-f` postfix. Similarly, if you want indexing in directories, you can add the same pattern with `!-d`, which will check if requested directory is on your document root.

So these two lines before the actual `RewriteRule` would do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```