# Editing .htaccess redirects to Error 404 Object not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently editing my .htaccess file to redirect any request to the public folder inside my project but Im just getting this error

> 404 Object not found

Below is the code in the .htaccess folder

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1
```

Im not very well acquainted with htaccess code, what is wrong with this?

**UPDATE**

Below is a summarized file structure in my project, if it helps

```
-projectfolder
|
|--.htaccess
|
|----includes
|
|----mvc
|
|----cache
|
|----public
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is .htaccess even enabled? Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630996/spoofing-a-404-not-found-error-with-htaccess

Comment: @anubhava - its at the root of the my project folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your .htaccess is not directly under `DocumentRoot`. Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```